# Could not resolve dependencies ... until the update interval has elapsed or updates are forced

Tags: java, maven, jena

While trying to compile Jena, I met the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jena-elephas-stats: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.jena:jena-elephas-stats:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.jena:jena-ele
phas-mapreduce:jar:tests:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.apache.org/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots
has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

What does it mean? What was cached and where? How to force update?

Comment: Are you really using a SNAPSHOT version?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are building with maven?

Build it with the parameter -U. It will force maven to get all the dependencies again.